# Button appearance animation in Datatemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-animation

I have a button inside a DataTemplate of a ListBox.

Whenever a button is added to the Listbox,I want to animate the appearance of the new button by setting the opacity from minimum to maximum.

How do I do this?

Comment: See my previous [`answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010396/wpf-databound-listbox-animate-on-add-but-not-scroll) - `ListBox Animate on Add but not Scroll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen to Loaded event. When Loaded wpf will trigger your animation.

Here is an example how you could achieve that:

```
<Button Height="23" Margin="102,95,100,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Opacity">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                             From="1"
                                             To="0"
                                             Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>    
        </Button>
```